# PHP Regex the nested section based on defined parent

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match a nested content section of the config based on the alias.

I have the base prototype working for matching single aliases over here:  https://regex101.com/r/1vwKsx/1 (section correctly matched to: `'template_path_stack' =>`)

HOWEVER, I want to select a section (which is re-used in the file) based on the section container.
In the link above, I need to only match the section which is inside: `controllers => factories`.

The problem is that the regex matches both (the correct one and the one from the outside). https://regex101.com/r/IrV0SN/1

Current regex:

```
('factories' => )(\[((?>[^\[\]]++|(?2))*)\])
```

Comment: Like https://regex101.com/r/elP51F/1?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Damn, you are good. That is perfect thanks! Add an answer and I will mark it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add an obligatory prefix to the regex and discard the matched text using `\K` operator:

```php
'controllers' => \[\s*\K('factories' => )(\[((?>[^][]++|(?2))*)])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/elP51F/1).

Here,

- `'controllers' => \[` - a `'controllers' => [` text
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` - discards the text matched so far from the current overall match memory buffer.